# Website shown different on Macbook than on Windows

Tags: html, css, wordpress, windows, macos

I really don't know what to do so I hope that maybe one of you can find the solution for this issue:

https://www.schwitzen.bubblfy.com/

This wordpress website is shown different on Windows than on Mac. So on my Windows Computer I am using Google Chrome. And even on Firefox it is the same site.

But when I use the website on a MAC, it looks completely different.  (Not the same font, not the same margin, etc..)

At the beginning I thougt, that maybe MAC's Safari Browser is the reason for this but even when I open Firefox on the MAX, it looks different. Why?

How can I adjust the site so, that it looks like on the Windows Version?

Hope you can help me!

Kind regards

Answer (score 1):

The browsers use fonts preintsalled in operating system and display text via font-family css.
The different operating systems have different font families pre-installed, and when a certain font is missing, it is silently substituted with another. Moreover, the font that is used for substitution may be a native to the OS and specific to that particular OS only.
The same font size can be displayed differently on different OS.
Besides fonts, there might be other problems of different website view such as rendering engine(webkit, presto...), browser version, client operating system, browser-specific code and etc.

Comment: First of all thank you for your explanation!! That helped me a little bit to understand it. But how can I solve this problem? If it's just the font, than it would be okay. But the elements are also slipped.